# What is the best FREE solution to implement one ETL project in MySql

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, etl

What is the best FREE solution to implement one ETL project in MySql?

I need to extract for analisys big amount of data, and put the results in other tables.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: It might help if you describe what you want to do...

Comment: I edit the Question I hope that now is easy to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pentaho Kettle (PDI) is open source and it has a **[community version here](http://kettle.pentaho.org/)**, which works quite good.

Answer (score 1):

Talend also does an excellent job for ETL and ELT.  You can take a look at this page on my website: http://www.hiregion.com/2010/01/data-loading-through-talend-etl-studio.html and related articles.  I have also loaded hundreds of thousands of rows to millions through MySQL bulk loading (LOAD DATA  INFILE syntax - dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html ) and then doing some transformations in MySQL.  You can do most of transformations before the load (ETL) or after load (ELT) or use hybrid technique.